# failure. state: 404, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Recently I have migrated to MobileFirst 7.1 from Worklight 6.1.But after migration i am able to access static pages but when i am trying to call any adapter I am getting server connection fails.

When I am trying to call an adapter from a browser I am able to get response but when I am call internally with in mobilefirst app, I am not able to connect to the server.

[check the response of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbePs.png)

Staging Environment Migration process:

I have taken two new servers for MF 7.1 in that I have installed WAS Liberty and MobileFirst server and after that I have taken worklight 6.1 wlapp and adapters and built it using MobileFirst 7.1 studio and deploy it on Mobilefirst 7.1 servers.

Comment: How did you migrate? Which steps did you follow? Edit your question with EVERYTHING you've done.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear where you are making this test... in a development or production server, but because it does not find the `preview` servlet / endpoint it does make it seem like you are testing this outside of the development environment.

In MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1 the preview servlet has been removed. It is available only during development (= in MobileFirst Studio plug-in for Eclipse) and not in stand-alone server installations.

Comment: Hi Idan, its a staging environment.since hit is not coming from webserver so we are trying with app servers but still we are not able to connect to the server

Comment: Ther error does not mean that you are unable to connect... the failure happens because you are trying to load a URL that does not exist. There is no preview in stand alone server installations.

Comment: When I am trying to call Mobilefirst adapters from the browser i am getting  response but calling with in app is not happening

Comment: From the browser - how

Comment: https://hostname/contextroot/invoke?adapter=eservice&procedure=getSectors&parameters=%5B%27en%27%2C%27%27%2C%27%27%2C%27%27%2C%27%27%5D

in this way I am able to call an adapter from outside network

Comment: That does not make sense. If you had tried to use your app in a physical device it would not have failed with "preview" error message. You are not telling the whole story or what exactly it is that you're doing.

Comment: Provide the client side logs - logcat or from XCode console when you are running the application on the device